# ROS Indigo: Where is rqt_plot

Tags: ros-indigo, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I try wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics and want to run

$ rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot

but it says

**[rospack] Error: package 'rqt_plot' not found**

In the rqt_gui it is not listed in the plugins. I have installed ros-indigo-desktop-full

Is it possible to get rqt_plot running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172663/ros-indigo:-where-is-rqt_plot/) by [fhurlbrink](https://answers.ros.org/users/18571/fhurlbrink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible that rqt_plot isn't included in the desktop-full variant for some reason. Have you tried installing it manually?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt-plot
```

If it turns out that it's installable but isn't included in desktop-full, that's probably a bug in the desktop-full variant.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-06-03**:
You're right, I was able to install manually on 14.04.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-03**:
Ok. I've filed https://github.com/ros/metapackages/issues/4 for this.

**Comment by [fhurlbrink](https://answers.ros.org/users/18571/fhurlbrink/) on 2014-06-04**:
Well, now I have installed it manually.

But now, when I execute

$ rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot

it says:

[DEBUG] rqt_plot.plot: import of PyQtGraphDataPlot failed (trying other backends)
qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "rqt_plot"

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-06-04**:
@hurlbrink Please do not ask a new question in comment area, and try google your issue before you ask (I'm sure there's another question regarding your current issue). Also, be sure not to forget to mark this post as an answer if it solved your issue ;)

**Comment by [fhurlbrink](https://answers.ros.org/users/18571/fhurlbrink/) on 2014-06-05**:
OK, sorry. I'm new to ROS answers. I saw the PyQtGraph problem as a part of the rqt-plot issue. But now, I have googled it and so I found out, this is a separate issues independent from existing of rqt_plot in Indigo and solved it.